# Export pandas frame with styling format into excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel, styling

I have a data frame with a column already formatted. When I tried to export it to excel with the code:

```
`export_excel = df.to_excel(r’path, index: None, header=True`
```

The excel file doesn’t have the formatting like the data frame. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you specify the formatting please?

Comment: So the formatting is: df = df.style.apply(lambda row: np.repeat(‘background color: lightgreen’ if row.isnull() else ‘’, row.shape[0]), axis = 1)

Comment: The idea for formatting is that it would highlight any rows that have nan with light green color

Comment: I don't think pandas can export to excel with those features, instead, you should try using `XlsxWriter` . Here is a full guide, if you have questions about the code, I'll try to answer the question with the code. https://pbpython.com/improve-pandas-excel-output.html

Comment: Thanks. Let me read the docs

Comment: For the #add total rows, he has a line of code like formula=“SUM({:s}:{:s})”.format(start_range, end_range). I wonder what the function sum is doing?

Comment: It's just creating an extra row with the total sum of the row values from start_range to end_range. This is made for each column in the dataset, because it belongs to a for loop. Could you get the format as you desired?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven’t been able to. Could you help me with it a bit. I’m using conditional_format. The criteria is =isblank(T:T) =True but it doesn’t work. Pretty much just want to check if column T has blank values. If any row does, then highlight that row in green

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198389/discussion-between-celius-stingher-and-dat-nguyen).